# "Required" validation attribute not working in asp.net mvc 3 while others work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have a weird situation where I have created a separate validation class for my Entity object:

```
   [MetadataType(typeof(TopTenFav_Validation))]
public partial class TopTenFav
{

}
public class TopTenFav_Validation
{

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Youtube link is Required")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage="Youtube link cannot exceed 100 characters")]
    [Range(10,20)]
    public string YoutubeLink { get; set; }


    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Youtube link cannot exceed 50 characters")]
    [Required]
    [MinLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Youtube link cannot be shorter than 30 characters")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

The Entity object's name is the same as my validation class - TopTenFav, so as I red it should automatically map the validation logic to my Entity Framework objects. I have a little form where I mapped textboxes to the model as follows:

```
         <div>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.topTenFav.YoutubeLink, new { id = "youTubeLinkTxt"          })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.topTenFav.YoutubeLink,"*")
        </div>

         <div>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.topTenFav.Title, new { id = "youTubeNameTxt" })
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.topTenFav.Title,"*")
        </div>
```

The problem is that the required attribute is not working while others work, meaning that when I leave the textboxes empty and I make an ajax call to the server the code passes on the success but when I type in data that doesnt pass the minLenght validator the code goes to the error part of my ajax call as I expected. So what am I missing here that the required validator is not firing up when my textboxes are empty?

```
    $(document).on("click", ".btnAddTopTenFav", function () {
        var btnClicked = $(this);
        var txtLink = $('#youTubeLinkTxt').val();
        var txtName = $('#youTubeNameTxt').val();
        var subLink = txtLink.substr(31); //.replace(/.*\?v=/, '');
        var rank = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
        $("#hiddenRank").val(rank);

        $.ajax({
            beforeSend: function () { ShowAjaxLoader(); },
            url: "/Home/AddTopTenFav/",
            type: "POST",
            data: $("#AddTopTenFavForm").serialize(),
            success: function (data) { HideAjaxLoader(), ShowMsg("Song Added Successfully"), $(btnClicked).replaceWith('<a name="' + subLink + '" class="savedLinks"  href="#" >' + txtName + '</a><span name=' + data + ' class="btnDeleteTopTenFavSong dontDoAnything">x</span'); },
            error: function () { HideAjaxLoader(), ShowMsg("Song could not be added, please try again") }
        });


  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddTopTenFav(HomeViewModel topTen)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var top = new TopTenFav();
            top.Date = DateTime.Now;
            top.Rank = topTen.topTenFav.Rank;
            top.UserName = User.Identity.Name;
            top.YoutubeLink = topTen.topTenFav.YoutubeLink;
            top.Title = topTen.topTenFav.Title;
            repository.AddTopTen(top);
            repository.Save();
            return this.Content(top.SongId.ToString());
        }
        else 
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Post the code for your controllers please

Comment: How are you invoking validation in your AJAX call.  Please add details about the call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you are not invoking validation to occur before you are posting.

The `MinLength` validators fire, because you are entering data into the field, then leaving it, which invokes the validation for that field.  However, the `Required` validators will only fire if invoked by the form's submit event, or if you manually invoke validation for the form.

Add the following to wrap the code in your `$(document).on("click", ".btnAddTopTenFav"` function:

```
$("form").validate().form();
if ($("form").valid())
{
    // insert the rest of your submission code here
}
```

This will invoke the validation, and will only submit if the form is valid.

Comment: one question tho, why u added .form() after validate. what does it do?

Comment: `form()` will cause all of the validation messages to be updated.

Comment: One more thing, when validation does not pass it shows a * and not my intended message..

Comment: And how would I fadeout or hide the validation message on textbox.focus for example?

Comment: If you have a custom message, then you should not declare `"*"` in your `ValidationMessageFor`.  For example, just declare `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.topTenFav.YoutubeLink)`.

Comment: Re: fadeout or hide messages.  That should be asked as a separate question.