# Set required to select validation for dropdown list in asp.net razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can I apply the selection required validation on dropdownlist in  asp.net razor without using model.
below is my DropDownList

```
<td>@Html.DropDownList("Units", new SelectList(@ViewBag.Settings.CdcPortalRentInfo 
         , "CdcPortalRentInfoId" , "Description")
         , new { style = "width:250px" })
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model just add data annotation :

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must select a RentInfo")]
    public int CdcPortalRentInfoId{ get; set; }
    public int Description{ get; set; } //I think this is you property
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this with required attribute in MVC

```
public class CdcPortalRentInfo 
{
      [Required(ErrorMessage="Your Error Message")]
      public int CdcPortalRentInfoId{ get; set; }

       public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: See- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345763/required-validation-attribte-not-working-in-asp-net-mvc-3-while-others-work

Comment: See another one- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734608/required-attribute-not-working-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: appropriately.Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected
Source Error:Line 19:<tr>                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(@ViewBag.Settings.CdcPortalRentInfo => @ViewBag.Settings.CdcPortalRentInfo.CdcPortalRentInfoId)                 
Line 22:                    <td> <div class="caption">Unit Type:<img alt="Required Field" height="18" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/ico_red_asterisk.png")" width="9" class="red" /></div></td>

Comment: How should i write @Html.ValidationMessageFor(@ViewBag.Settings.CdcPortalRentInfo => @ViewBag.Settings.CdcPortalRentInfo.CdcPortalRentInfoId)

Comment: Hi Jalpesh,I am not using model. I have to created a object and putting into vewbag. I am retrieving the object in view from VewBag and binding to dropdownlist. Now I need to provide the validation.

Comment: why you need to have object?